# jQuery replacing list items with different list items with specific classes

Tags: jquery, list, sorting, replace, onclick

I have a `list` and a `button`...

If someone clicks on the button, I want to replace the list items with different list items with a certain class. I have the classes already, but I don't know how to use `load` to `replace` it...

I have made this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#dynamic").click(function() {
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
         $('.remove-this-list-on-click').fadeOut("slow", function () {
             $(this).load("li a.add-this-list-on-click-instead > *").fadeIn("slow");
         });
     });
 });
 });
```

Here are the buttons and the list:

```
       <div id="dynamic">testestetest</div>
<ul class="most_popular" id="bla">
    <li class="remove-this-list-on-click"></li>
    <li class="remove-this-list-on-click"></li>
    <li><a class="add-this-list-on-click-instead"></a></li>
    <li><a class="add-this-list-on-click-instead"></a></li>
</ul>
```

So you can see that the list with the class `add-this-list-on-click-instead` is already there, so it should stay there actually. Maybe we can use the remove `remove-this-list-on-click` list items, but I don't know how... I guess this called **sorting** in your language.... I want to sort items on this click.

Here is the `jSfiddle` --> http://jsfiddle.net/aYtma/

Comment: I don't understand the goal of `setInterval()` and `.load()`. You can just create a css class with `display:none` and add it to all `add-this-on-click` elements, so they will be hidden. On the click event, fadeOut `remove-this-list` elements and fadeIn `add-this` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `.load` there, If, classes are already there, you don't have to do anything -

Simply remove this Line

```
 $(this).load("li a.add-this-list-on-click-instead > *").fadeIn("slow");
```

and if `.add-this-list-on-click-instead` are hidden initially -

then just make it visible with this -

```
$("#dynamic").click(function() {
     $this = $(this);
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
         $('.remove-this-list-on-click').fadeOut("slow", function () {
             $this.find("a.add-this-list-on-click-instead").fadeIn("slow");
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: last question: is there a way I can say: if clicked on this button, remove all other anchors beside one specific class? So a more generic thing. Removing not the one class, but all other anchors beside one?

Comment: @user1770896 Yes, `-->` `$('.someclas:not(".someOtherClass")').remove()`

Answer (score 1):

Your html is not correct. You have open quotes and incorrect closing braces.

corrected:

```
<div id="dynamic">testestetest</div>
<ul class="most_popular" id="bla">
    <li class="remove-this-list-on-click"></li>
    <li class="remove-this-list-on-click"></li>
    <li><a class="add-this-list-on-click-instead"></a></li>
    <li><a class="add-this-list-on-click-instead"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Now it will atleast start responding to your JS. Also you question is not clear whether you want to remove the items/sort the items/highlight or refresh the items. May be you should udpate your question.

Comment: I know that. That was just a test. Thanks anyway, I give you an upvote.